# State of the art GD and SGD convergence analysis for nonconvex problems

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

I am working on the convergence analysis of gradient descent as well as stochastic gradient descent. I have come across the following papers which are great papers.

1- [Lee et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04915.pdf) proving GD converges to local minimizer.

2- [Jin et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10456.pdf) accelerated gradient descent for escaping saddle points

3- [Jin et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00887.pdf) perturbed gradient descent converges to stationary points

4- [Allen-Zhu et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05643.pdf) convergence of stochastic gradient descent

> **Question:**
>   Please discuss the recent improvements in this area after the aforementioned papers and cite the relevant papers that are new. Also, provide more materials on SGD since I have only been able to find few papers regarding convergence of SGD.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249999/proof-for-convergence-of-stochastic-gradient-descent-to-a-local-optimum-for-non/3252892#3252892)

Comment: @madnessweasley: pretty much is what I wanted. Do you mind if I ask you to shed lights on this topic if you come across new things?

Comment: I no longer keep up with that line of research, so I'm afraid I won't be able to keep the answer up-to-date. You can keep tabs on the [stat.ML](https://arxiv.org/list/stat.ML/recent) and [math.OC](https://arxiv.org/list/math.OC/recent) arXiv threads to stay updated (of course, I ignored many lines of research in my previous answer)